# Highchart - position x-axis label bottom to next label

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart created with highchart and here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxka14wp/)

```
$(function () {

var seriesData = [["apple",29.9], ["banana",71.5], ["orange",106.4], ["mango",106.4], ["mango",106.4], ["mango",106.4], ["mango",106.4], ["mango",106.4], ["mango",106.4], ["mango",106.4],];     
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            formatter: function() { return seriesData[this.value][0];
            },
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: seriesData     
    }]
});
});
```

and it have many labels placed on x-axis and i can not use rotation option. This is the output i would like to achieve
[image: X-Axis format]

Comment: you can check out this label property of Highchart https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.align

Comment: that property only aligns the text either to "left" or "right" of the tick, what i expect is different as you can see in output image.

Comment: you want label up and down but I don't things so highchart provide this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `staggerLines: 2` in your `xAxis` labels, like this:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    staggerLines: 2,
    ...
  },
  ...
},
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/ktgd5h98/

**API on staggerlines:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.staggerLines

Comment: Thanks, You really made my day